# how to fix: system.typeinitializationException:the type initializer for "WinRT.Activationfactory 1' threw an exception

Tags: window, tesseract, media-player

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsvjP.png)

system.typeinitializationException:the type initializer for "WinRT.Activationfactory 1' threw an exception -->System.Runtime.interopServices.COMException (0x80040155):ClassFactory cannot supply requested class

Basically, i am trying to install a un traducteur de jeu utilisant Tesseract OCR. La méthode de fonctionnement est un programme qui capture la boîte de dialogue sur l'écran du jeu sous forme d'image, extrait la boîte de dialogue à l'aide de l'OCR et traduit la boîte de dialogue du jeu à l'aide du traducteur DB ou des traductions BING.However before launching it ask me to install NET 7.0 Desktop Runtime which i do  but now when starting i got this error. Could you help?

i try the most basic action which is restart my computer and see if it's working but nothing. I will like more suggestion before being too technical